# Cut part of every line in file possible?

Tags: notepad++, cut

I need to cut/copy part of lines only - is this possible in notepad++?

See image for (maybe) better explanation - I need to cut/copy the blue square.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to specify exactly what you want: remove everything between certain columns, regardless of text; remove a particular text, regardless of position, or only between certain columns; remove the second field in each line, regardless of the spacing between fields?

Comment: With your example you could use a program that can handle csv files and have an easy UI to copy that column. But as AFH said you will have to be more specific with what kind of data you're handling and what kind of pattern they actually have.

Comment: Thanks , this took away all needed , but as my files conains names of devices which are within 4-5 positions , I can remove these manually . File lines are like this  " 12.july 2017 23:56:08 The blue fox in device gggggg is down" , wth different lenghts of text and also device name.     But will save yr solution as it will coem handy when the text is not so close to being aligned .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as AFH said - its possible. All you have to do is simply use
**Alt** + **Mouse** dragging or **Alt** + **Shift** + **Arrow keys** to switch to *column mode*.

I think you can also use the **Begin/End Select** feature (*Alt+Shift+Arrow* is kind of unnecessary i think) 
So what do you need to do is:

- **Left mouse click** at the beginning of the wanted section
- Select the **Begin/End Section** command (the menu option is automatically checked)
- Go to the location where the wanted selection must **stop**
- Move the cursor to that second and final location, with:

a) A **left click** to set the future normal *selection*

b) A hit on the **ALT** key and a **left click**, simultaneously, to set the future *column mode* selection

- Select, again, the **Begin/End Select** command (The menu option is automatically unchecked), to generate the appropriate selection

Thats it!